# Is Flux zero when electric potential is zero?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity, electric-fields, gauss-law

A point P at the exact half way of two charges of same sign will have zero electric field intensity. According to Gauss's Law when I draw a spherical gaussian surface such that one of the charges is its centre and the gaussian surface is passing through point P, clearly the flux at point P will be non zero. But Φ=E.A,(this relation tells me zero E => zero Φ).

Comment: What is the connection with the potential?  Do you mean the electric field?

Comment: Could it be that you confuse flux $\Phi$ with electric potential $\Phi$?

Answer (score 1):

Gauss's law says that
$$\int_\mathcal{S}\mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{S}=\frac{Q_\text{enc}}{\epsilon_0}$$
which says that flux through the closed surface equals $1/\epsilon_0$ times of $Q_\text{enc}$. Now it is possible that the electric field at any point on the surface is zero. That doesn't make the electric flux to be zero as it's sum through all the points on the surface.

In other words,
$$\int_\mathcal{S}\mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{S}=\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty \\\text{each}\  \Delta S_l\rightarrow 0}\sum_{l=1}^N\mathbf{E}(x_l,y_l,z_l)\cdot \mathbf{n}_l\Delta S_l$$

So it might possible that for some $l$, $\mathbf{E}=0$ but that would not make the sum equal to zero. The sum will be zero if each term in the sum would be zero.

---

Edit: Please note that it necessary that to flux to be zero, each term must be zero. The terms might cancel each other or it might be zero due to dot product etc.

Comment: You want to be careful here as the sum could be $0$ with no terms being $0$, since two non-zero $\vec E$-field could superpose at a point to give a net $\vec E=0$.

Comment: Yes you are right that's why I haven't use only or iff, there might be other reason for which the flux become zero.

Comment: I have added a brief explanation on it.

Answer (score 1):

The flux $\Phi$ in Gauss' law is the *net* flux through the Gaussian surface.  It is perfectly possible for the field to be $0$ at one point but the net flux over the surface be non-zero.

In order to infer $\vec E$ from Gauss's law, it is essential that
$\vec E\cdot d\vec S$ be constant on the surface.  This is clearly not the case here, *i.e.* the $\vec E$ is not constant on your surface since clearly $0$ at $P$ but would be non-zero on the point opposite $P$.  Hence you cannot use Gauss's law to deduce the value of $\vec E$ at $P$ using this surface.

Moreover, even if $\Phi=0$ there is no guarantee that $\vec E=0$, as illustrated by this example

[image]

of a box containing no charge plunged in a constant $\vec E$-field.  This is another case where $\vec E\cdot d\vec S$ is not constant on the surface since
$\vec E\cdot d\vec S$ is $0$ on the sides parallel to the field, negative on the right panel perpendicular to $\vec E$, and positive on the left panel perpendicular to $\vec E$.

To repeat: Gauss's law can only be used to infer the field when $\vec E\cdot d\vec S$ is constant on the Gaussian surface.